# How do I count the number of characters in a file using scanner and output it?

Tags: file, input, java.util.scanner, counting, string-length

I am currently working on a program and cannot figure out why whenever I print the length it does not print out the correct number. Both uppercase and lowercase work correctly.

An example Input would be:

> I
>
> Love
>
> Programming

The output would then be:

> Number of characters is 16.
>
> Number of lower case letters is 13.
>
> Number of upper case letters is 3.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
    int lowercase = 0;
    int uppercase = 0;
    int length = 0;
    File file1 = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file1);
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
    String s = scanner.nextLine();
    length = s.length();
    char[] charAnalysis = s.toCharArray();
    for (char element : charAnalysis) 
    {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(element)) 
        {
            uppercase++;
        }
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(element)) 
        {
            lowercase++;
        }
        length = s.length();
    }
    }
    File file2 = new File("output.txt");
        try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file2)) 
        {
            ps.println("Number of characters is " + length);
            ps.println("Number of lower case letters is " + lowercase);
            ps.println("Number of upper case letters is " + uppercase);   
        }
        catch(IOException e) 
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"...whenever I print the length it does not print out the correct number"* What do you think the correct number is? What do you see instead? Why do you think the code would produce the first one instead? What do you see when you run this with the debugger built into your IDE? (Using a debugger is **not** an advanced skill. It's basically the first thing you should learn after "Hello, world" and **incredibly** useful when learning to program.)

Answer (score 0):

Each loop you overwrite the length variable, with the length of the current line. What you should change is to add the length of the current line to your total. So remove both your `length = s.length();` and replace it by one `length += s.length();` statement. I assume you don't want to count newline characters. See code below:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int lowercase = 0;
    int uppercase = 0;
    int length = 0;
    File file1 = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file1);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

      String s = scanner.nextLine();
      length += s.length();
      System.out.println("new length = " + length);
      char[] charAnalysis = s.toCharArray();
      for (char element : charAnalysis) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(element)) {
          uppercase++;
        }
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(element)) {
          lowercase++;
        }
      }
    }
    File file2 = new File("output.txt");
    try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file2)) {
      ps.println("Number of characters is " + length);
      ps.println("Number of lower case letters is " + lowercase);
      ps.println("Number of upper case letters is " + uppercase);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```